# where to Download Sitecore.support.98798 patch

Tags: sitecore8.2

Our Speak ribbon keep on loading for the xperience editor in sitecore. While googling, I found there is some support patch available for this issue. So I want to know From where can I download Sitecore.support.98798 patch.

Regards,
Saibalini

Answer (score 0):

You can directly contact Sitecore support and mention about the error you're facing and this patch. If patch is applicable to your solution, they will share it with you in no time.